# How to do a Range Bucket on a Count returned by a Group By query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was hoping if you can help me.

I am in a situation where I first need to do a Count Distinct of Funds and Group By Policies. Once I have done that, I need to put the count of policies in Range of Number of Funds.

This is the data available, where you can see the policies and different funds linked to it

```
**PolicyNum Fund** 
1201        AB
1202        AC
1203        AB
1203        AC
1203        AD
1204        AB
1204        BC
1204        AC
1204        AD
1204        AE
1204        AF
```

Now I need to do a Count Distinct of Fund Grouped by Policy. 
I have used this query to do that:

```
select fv, policy, count(distinct fv.fund)
  from policy_fund fv
 group by fv.policy
 order by count(distinct fv.fund) desc
```

After using the above code, the following would come up
This is a view where you can see the number of funds linked to each policy

```
**Policy    No. of Funds**
1201    1
1202    1
1203    3
1204    6
```

Now, the problem part, I want to reach to this, which is the Range of Number of Funds and how many policies fall under that range of funds:

Help required to achieve this view of Range of Number of Funds and how many policies are present in each range

```
**Range of Number of funds  Number of policies**
0 to 1                       2
2 to 3                       1
4 to 5                       0
5 to 6                       1
```

Comment: `select fv, policy,` should be `select fv.policy,`?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to make the question visually appealing. But those HTML tables aren't needed. In fact ASCII (or technically maybe Unicode) ones are sufficient and easier to consume (if one wants to create an actual data set from them). So I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can left join your query to a derived table defining the ranges on the count being in the range and then group by the range and count the policies.

```
SELECT r.l || ' to ' || r.u "RANGE",
       count(p) "COUNT"
       FROM (SELECT 0 l,
                    1 u
                    FROM dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 l,
                    3 u
                    FROM dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 l,
                    5 u
                    FROM dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 l,
                    7 u
                    FROM dual) r
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT fv.policy p,
                              count(distinct fv.fund) cof
                              FROM policy_fund fv
                              GROUP BY fv.policy) fpp
                      ON fpp.cof >= r.l
                         AND fpp.cof <= r.u
      GROUP BY r.l,
               r.u
      ORDER BY r.l,
               r.u;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c81f512c2216983dc2a1807f7d322e97)